# Extending a Select.... to accommodate more fields as extension using EF

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, projection

I have a class:

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Salary { get; set; }

  public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

And query using Entity Framework is:

```
var selectedEmployee = entities.Employees
                             .Where(e=>e.Salary>10000)
                             .Select(emp => new EmpDTO
                                  {
                                      Id = emp.Id,
                                      Name = emp.Name,
                                      Salary = emp.Salary
                                  });
```

My question is:
I want to allow extending this query without rewriting the base query. It should allow adding a new field in the .Select(.....) by extending the above query.

Without rewriting the complete query:

```
var selectedEmployee = entities.Employees
                                 .Where(e=>e.Salary>10000)
                                 .Select(emp => new EmpDTO
                                      {
                                          Id = emp.Id,
                                          Name = emp.Name,
                                          Salary = emp.Salary,

                                          Address = emp.Address

                                      });
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you can try this:

```
public IQuerable<EmpDTO> GetEmployee(Func<Employee, EmpDTO> projection = null)
{
    if(projection == null)
        projection = emp => new EmpDTO {
                                  Id = emp.Id,
                                  Name = emp.Name,
                                  Salary = emp.Salary,    
                                };
    return entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Salary > 10000).Select(projection);
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
var query = classInstance.GetEmployee();
//or
query = classInstance.GetEmployee(emp => new EmpDTO {
                                          Id = emp.Id,
                                          Name = emp.Name,
                                          Salary = emp.Salary,    
                                          Address = emp.Address
                                      });
```

> If you always want to get some set of fields, like `Id`, `Name` and
>   `Salary` and sometimes take additional fields(and specify only their
>   as method arguments), you should to take all fields from DB and only
>   then filter them depends on your condition - it is bad practice to do
>   **SELECT ***, so you should get default set of fields or specify **all** desired fields mannualy.

**Solution with SELECT *:**

```
public List<EmpDTO> GetEmployee(Func<Employee, EmpDTO> projection)
{
    var query = entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Salary > 10000).ToList().Select(x => {
         var item = projection == null ? new EmpDTO() : projection(x);
         item.Id = x.Id;
         item.Name = x.Name;
         item.Salary = x.Salary;
         return item;
     }).ToList();
}
```

> At this case return value is `List<T>` not `IQuerable<T>`;

**Implementation:**

```
var items = classInstance.GetEmployee(emp => new EmpDTO { Address = emp.Address });
//items also will contain fields: Id, Name and Salary by default
```

Comment: Is it possible to Append the Address without rewriting the entire select?
query = classInstance.GetEmployee(emp => new EmpDTO {
                                          Id = emp.Id,
                                          Name = emp.Name,
                                          Salary = emp.Salary,    
                                          Address = emp.Address
                                      });

Comment: Yes, it is my first variant, where projection is variable.